# affineness vs geometric affineness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be $k$-scheme of finite type, $k$ being a (perfect) field, and assume $X\otimes\overline{k}$ is affine. Is $X$ necessarily an affine scheme? What about if $X$ is a $k$-group scheme?

Comment: The property of a morphism (such as structural morphism to an affine base) being affine descends through any fpqc base change.  This follows from Serre's cohomological criterion for affineness (which is valid for qcqs schemes) coupled with the compatibility of formation of quasi-coherent sheaf cohomology with respect to flat base change (for qcqs schemes). 

Comment: Again I wonder why BCnrd does not write this as an answer ... it's perfect!

Comment: Once he explained to me his reason for doing so...but anyway, this answers my question. Thanks, Brian!